# Flex forcing resizing when the image source update is completed

Tags: image, events, apache-flex

I update the source property of an image. When the image is loaded I want to redraw the border skin to fit the new size of the image.

```
newImgEdit.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImgComplete);
newImgEdit.source = myurl_ressource;

private function loadImgComplete(evt:Event):void {
    trace("redraw !!");
    //invalidateDisplayList();
    this.setStyle("borderSkin", ShapeContainerBorderOn);
    var img:Image = evt.currentTarget as Image;
    img.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImgComplete);
}
```

The trace "redraw" seems to happen once the image is loaded but the border still does not get redrawn with the correct height and width.

Do I need to remove the listener or will it be garbage-collected later?

Comment: Is the image control you're using loading an image of the same dimensions, or different dimensions?  When you say, "with the good height and width," could you explain what appears to happen visually?  Then I could probably throw in with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can [manually force a component to update its layout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf633a0-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7dfd) by calling `validateNow()`.